# Uploadify completes but doesn't upload

Tags: php, uploadify

I am trying to use Uploadify on my site and have it setup with the following uploadify.php:

```
<?php
// Define a destination
//$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
  echo '1';
} else {
  echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}
?>
```

It wasn't uploading so I commented out $targetFolder and changed $targetPath so that it is just the document root. This results in $targetFile being /home/user/public_html/example.com/file.txt when I try to upload file.txt with Uploadify. The folder is set to 755. I'm at a loss as to what the problem could be. I am otherwise using a vanilla install of Uploadify and everything seems to work fine except that the file never actually goes where it should.

Comment: move_uploaded_file should return a warning if it fails

Comment: $foo=move_uploaded_file ... var_dump($foo);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the folder permissions not staying set to 755. I logged out of and back into cPanel and everything's working now.